# Problemas com xml para transformar em data.frame em R

Tags: r, xml

Boa noite

Necessito de uma colaboração em xml, tenho pouco conhecimento para R nisso

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de xml

Para me ajudarem, por favor copiem em um txt e salvem em formato xml para usarem

```
<arquivoposicao_4_01>
<fundo>
<titpublico>
 <dtemissao>20080509</dtemissao>
 <dtoperacao>20110614</dtoperacao>
 <dtvencimento>20140907</dtvencimento>
 <qtdisponivel>0</qtdisponivel>
 <qtgarantia>114</qtgarantia>
 <depgar>5</depgar>
 <caracteristica>N</caracteristica>
 <percprovcred>0</percprovcred>
 <classeoperacao>C</classeoperacao>
 <idinternoativo>227549    </idinternoativo>
 <nivelrsc></nivelrsc>
</titpublico>
</fundo>
</arquivoposicao_4_01>
```

Ao salvar isso , faço a importação dos dados

```
dados<-xmlParse(file = choose.files())
```

E tento transformar em data.frame, mas o resultado não é o esperado

```
dados2<-xmlToDataFrame(dados)
```

Eu gostaria de resultar em um data frame, onde cada linha seria respectiva a cada item do xml, porém o resultado é que tudo junto , ficando impossível separar

desde já agradeço

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É muito raro você encontrar um XML que já está na estrutura certa para transformá-lo em um `data.frame`. O ideal é você transformar o arquivo para uma lista e aí extrair da lista o que você precisar. Supondo que o seu arquivo em XML se chama `arquivo.XML` então o seguinte código lerá o XML e o transformará em uma lista:

```
xml_arquivo <- xmlParse(file = 'arquivo.XML')
xml_lista <- xmlToList(xml_arquivo)
```

resultando na seguinte lista:

```
$fundo
$fundo$titpublico
$fundo$titpublico$isin
[1] "BRSTNCLF1QR4"

$fundo$titpublico$codativo
[1] "210100"

$fundo$titpublico$cusip
[1] "STNCLF1QR"

$fundo$titpublico$dtemissao
[1] "20080509"

$fundo$titpublico$dtoperacao
[1] "20110614"

$fundo$titpublico$dtvencimento
[1] "20140907"

$fundo$titpublico$qtdisponivel
[1] "0"

$fundo$titpublico$qtgarantia
[1] "114"

$fundo$titpublico$depgar
[1] "5"

$fundo$titpublico$pucompra
[1] "4722.758614"

$fundo$titpublico$puvencimento
[1] "1"

$fundo$titpublico$puposicao
[1] "5481.16800311"

$fundo$titpublico$puemissao
[1] "1000"

$fundo$titpublico$principal
[1] "538394.48"

$fundo$titpublico$tributos
[1] "0"

$fundo$titpublico$valorfindisp
[1] "0"

$fundo$titpublico$valorfinemgar
[1] "624853.15"

$fundo$titpublico$coupom
[1] "0"

$fundo$titpublico$indexador
[1] "SEL"

$fundo$titpublico$percindex
[1] "100"

$fundo$titpublico$caracteristica
[1] "N"

$fundo$titpublico$percprovcred
[1] "0"

$fundo$titpublico$classeoperacao
[1] "C"

$fundo$titpublico$idinternoativo
[1] "227549    "

$fundo$titpublico$nivelrsc
NULL
```

e pronto! Digamos que você queira acessar a data de vencimento do título. Basta fazer isso:

```
xml_lista$fundo$titpublico$dtvencimento
[1] "20140907"
```

Com a função `as.Date()` você consegue até um resultado muito melhor

```
as.Date(xml_lista$fundo$titpublico$dtvencimento, format = "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2014-09-07"
```

Por fim você consegue transformar a lista em um data.frame se você quiser:

```
dados = as.data.frame(unlist(xml_lista$fundo$titpublico))
```

Comment: obrigado , ajudou muito , vou tentar dar escala para o arquivo completo

Comment: @Henrique Faria de Oliveira, estou com um problema parecido com o seu, mas não estou conseguindo resposta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426692/transformar-xml-em-dataframe